# jquery file upload submit callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

im using the blueimp jquery file upload plugin . this code

```
<script>
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit',function(e,data){
        var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
        if (inputs.filter('[required][value=""]').first().focus().length){
            return false;
        }
        data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
    });
                </script>
```

is supposed to send all files along with the form data to the server. For some reason its not working . Firebug says ReferenceError: $ is not defined when this page is loaded. Should i define this callback in the main js ? ( I am able to add additional form data for the selected files when uploading and save the names onto the database. When using titles for each uploaded file these values are sent saved as typed when uploaded one by one. When uploaded all at once the value is the same as the first input. This callback supposedly uploads thses data one by one.

Comment: Did you include the jqueryFile before inserting your own js? otherwise you have to change the order of your script files.

Comment: yes i did. doesnt work. Im pretty new to jquery. Should i define fileuploadsubmit in a seperate js file ?

Comment: try using `jQuery` rather than `$`

Comment: ddnt work.. Could you please have a look at the jsfiddle code i attached ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

As shown in your jsfiddle, all the script includes are placed at the bottom of the page. So you either move them before your script tags, or you move your script tags to the bottom of the page. Otherwise jQuery will not be defined when you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this :

```
(e, data>
```

to

```
 (e, data)
```